# BlocListener doesn't listen a changing state

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, bloc, state-management

I try to solve that problem a couple of days, but I can't. I have a login form, when user signs in, the LoginBloc changes its state to LogIn() and BlocListener(which is located in HomeView.dart) must change HomeBloc's state from Initial() to Loaded(), but it doesn't work. I don't know why but BlocListener ignores that LoginBloc has LogIn() state and doesn't run HomeBlocEvent.loadUserDetails()
I appreciate any help or pieces of advice how to solve this problem.
I used Firebase as Authentication service.

```dart
// LoginBloc.dart
@injectable
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  final UserSignInImpl _userSignInImpl;

  LoginBloc(this._userSignInImpl) : super(const LoginState.initial()) {
    on<SignIn>((event, emit) async {
      emit(const LoginState.loading());
      final result = await _userSignInImpl.call(event.user);
      result.fold((error) {
        emit(LoginState.loadFailed(error));
      }, (success) {
        emit(LoginState.logIn(user: success));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```dart
  // HomeView.dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final homeBloc = BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context);
    final loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);
      ......
      body: BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          state.maybeWhen(
            // function below isn't called, but LoginState is LogIn()
            logIn: (user) => homeBloc.add(
              HomeEvent.loadUserDetails(user.email!),
            ),
            orElse: () {},
          );
        },
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
            const HomeSliverAppBar(),
          ],
          body: BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
            bloc: homeBloc,
            builder: (context, state) {
              return state.maybeWhen(
                loaded: (userInfo) => const HomeListView(),
                // TODO: implement shimmer view
                orElse: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

```dart
// HomeBloc.dart
@injectable
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  HomeBloc() : super(const HomeState.initial()) {
    on<LoadUserDetails>((event, emit) async {
      emit(const HomeState.loading());
      await fbFireStore.getUserDetails(event.email).then(
            (userDetails) => emit(HomeState.loaded(user: userDetails)),
          );
    });
    on<SignOut>((event, emit) async {
      await fbAuth.signOut();
    });
  }
}
```

```dart
  // LoginView.dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);
  .....
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: AppStyles.widePurpleButtonStyle,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_signInKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                           // Adding SignIn() event                            
                           loginBloc.add(LoginEvent.signIn(LoginUser(
                              email: _emailController.text.trim(),
                              password: _passwordController.text.trim(),
                            )));
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(S.of(context).logIn),
                      ),
    .....
                   SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height * 0.05,
                    child: BlocConsumer<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        return state.maybeWhen(
                          loading: () {
                            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                          },
                          orElse: () {
                            return const SizedBox();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      listener: (context, state) {
                        state.maybeWhen(
                          loadFailed: (failure) {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return ErrorAlertDialog(error: failure);
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          logIn: (_) {
                            context.router.navigate(const HomeRoute());
                          },
                          orElse: () {},
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

BlocListener must run HomeEvent.loadUserDetails() when LoginBloc's state is LogIn()

Comment: Why state.maybeWhen ?

Comment: Hmm, because I need to run LoadUserDetails event only when LoginState is LogIn(), otherwise it doesn't matter.
Do you think this could be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that when `LoginBloc` emits `LoginState.logIn()` your `HomeView` is not yet in the Navigation stack. Note that you are performing `context.router.navigate(const HomeRoute());` inside listener of `BlocConsumer<LoginBloc, LoginState>()` in `LoginView`.

So when `HomeView` is actually opened `LoginBloc` state is `LoginState.logIn()` already and no other states are emitted by `LoginBloc` and that's why your listener in `HomeView` is not receiving anything.

To access user details inside `HomeView` you can just get `LoginBloc` state:

```
final state = loginBloc.state; // LoginState.login(user: ...)
```

But I suggest just to pass a `user email` as a parameter for `HomeView`  and then use it to load user details.

Comment: Sure, I added LoginView.dart where LoginBloc is used

Comment: @rel1nce Is code inside `on<SignIn>((event, emit) async {})` reachable? Did you try to debug it? Would be really nice if you can add your reproducable sample to github so I can try it on my end

Comment: Yep, SignIn event works without any problems. If it doesn't, Autoroute won't navigate to homeView page. The project codebase is available here: https://github.com/rel1nce/Mapping/tree/master

Comment: @rel1nce Okay, I checked your code and found the problem. Please check an updated answer

Comment: Oh man thank you a lot for your detailed answer, it finally works